# Android SDK Zip - Windows 64bit Home Variable

Tags: java, android, windows-7, sdk

I'm using the android_sdk.zip version, since I don't feel comfortable using installers on Windows systems. However, I understand that I need to set the Home variable in order for the SDKManager.exe to run properly. I tried another method posted on stackoverflow, but if I do that, then both Eclipse and Netbeans, won't find Java anymore.

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin';'"

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there may be a bug in the installer for Windows, as I haven't seen it work properly at detecting a JDK on Windows 7 at all.

If you are planning on developing in Eclipse, it isn't even required.  You'll save yourself a lot of time and headache if you just download and install the SDK zip file (instead of the installer EXE).

1. Download and unpack this file somewhere on your machine
2. Install the ADT plugin into Eclipse
3. Point ADT to the location you unzipped the SDK in Preferences

HTH